# How to run a program via Gradle task with arbitrary amount of arguments

Tags: gradle

Gradle ( I use last release 2.12) provides type: Exec parent task, but I cannot find out how to use it with multiple arguments.

For example I need to drop Postgresql database

```
dropdb --if-exists mydbname
```

But this do not work

```
task dropDatabase(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'dropdb', '--if-exists', 'mydbname'
}
```

and this also

```
task dropDatabase(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'dropdb'
    args '--if-exists', 'mydbname'
}
```

I tried many combinations but all failed with errors: output not set or wrong arguments.

But I need to run smth like this:

```
gunzip -c /Users/name/Downloads/db_31_03_2016_01_18_17.gz | psql -U postgres
```

How to do it?

Comment: error is always "Task has not declared any outputs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task

```
task dropDatabase(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'dropdb', '--if-exists', 'mydbname'
}
```

is correct. I test it and it works perfectly. As I understand your problem comes from this command

```
gunzip -c /Users/name/Downloads/db_31_03_2016_01_18_17.gz | psql -U postgres
```

and more precisely from the pipe `|` in it.

Effectively, you can't use a pipe in a `commandLine` property. The solution is to run your command within a bash interpreter. For this use the `-c` option of the `bash` command :

```
task myTask(type: Exec) {
    commandLine "bash" "-c" "gunzip -c /Users/name/Downloads/db_31_03_2016_01_18_17.gz | psql -U postgres"
}
```

With this solution the pipe is processed by the bash interpreter and not by gradle.

Comment: And one question more, may be know, how to pass arguments from one task from another? The docs are vague as seemed to me.

Comment: I think, it's better to open a new question for this.